# How to switch between multiple anchorPanes with MenuBar on top?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm new to `JavaFX` and I need to switch between multiple `Anchor Panes` using a `MenuBar`, so the `MenuBar` needs to stay on top when I'm switching between these Anchor Panes, I'm using `Scene Builder` to generate the `.FXML` files, but have no idea how to do this without creating multiple `MenuBars` for each Anchor Pane.

My question is how to do this in a simple way? Because I have ready to use Anchor Panes, all I need is a way to share the Menu bar on top of these Anchor panes.

Comment: Just use a [`BorderPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html), put the menu in the top, and then you can call `setCenter(...)` with whichever anchor pane you need to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James Commented, to do this you need to use borderPane with the `MenuBar` on top of it, and set your Anchor panes inside it using the `setCenter()` method on the `BoderPane`, like this:

```
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    private AnchorPane achor1;
    private AnchorPane achor2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            // TODO
            achor1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(("/Views/anchor1.fxml")));
            achor2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Views/anchor2.fxml"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CrechHomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    public void action1() throws IOException {
        // anchor1

        borderPane.setCenter(achor1);

    }

    @FXML
    public void action2() {
        //anchor2 

        borderPane.setCenter(achor2);
    }
```